# Browser.Load is spawning a new Process when trying to load new URL

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I have embedded CefSharp Browser for WPF Application where I'm trying to load a WebPage. Also I have bound JavaScript object using 
RegisterJsObject Function. This is required as JS of Webpage makes calls to Native app.

I have implemented a WatchDogTimer to switch to error page if the page load takes time/any error.
The issue is, when it tries to load Error page in case of timeout, it is killing the existing CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe and creating a new one. But this is losing the JavaScript binding thereby no calls can be made from JS to Native App.

Is there any way to avoid creating new process of CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe?

Comment: Please see my answer below on how to prevent creation of a new processes. But I am not 100% sure if it will resolve the problem with missing JavaScript binding. Can you please let me know what is the URL of your initial web page and what is the url of your error page?

Comment: If you are using legacy binding then this is expected, see http://cefsharp.github.io/api/71.0.0/html/P_CefSharp_CefSharpSettings_LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled.htm

Comment: Using the newer binding method is the best option https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#3-how-do-you-expose-a-net-class-to-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can use CefSettings class to change this behavior. By default, Chromium creates a renderer process for each instance of a site the user visits, but you can change it

```
var settings = new CefSettings();

settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("renderer-process-limit", "0");    

Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

Note, that you must do it before you create a first instance of your ChromiumWebBrowser.

**Important Note**: as [amaitland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4583726/amaitland) mentioned in his comment below you should use it very carefully and

> only if you are using a single browser instance should you even
>   consider doing this. Multiple instances hosted in a single process can
>   easily run out of memory, a single crash and they all stop working.
>   Also if the render process crashes for whatever reason, the new
>   instance won't have the objects bound.
>
> If you are using legacy binding then this is expected, see http://cefsharp.github.io/api/71.0.0/html/P_CefSharp_CefSharpSettings_LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled.htm
>
> Using the newer binding method is the best option https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#3-how-do-you-expose-a-net-class-to-javascript

Comment: There should be a big fat warning accompanying this answer, only if you are using a single browser instance should you even consider doing this. Multiple instances hosted in a single process can easily run out of memory, a single crash and they all stop working. Also if the render process crashes for whatever reason, the new instance won't have the objects bound.

Comment: It is clear that it is dangerous to use this settings when you want to build like "another browser" based on CefSharp where you want to open multiple websites at the same time. But I do not think it is the case here, is not it?

Comment: Experience says you must include a disclaimer, people will copy and paste any old code and use it out of context without giving it a second thought. It's amazing how often that happens. The safest option in my opinion is to use the newer binding method and get a reliable result.

Comment: Agree, I have updated my answer above. Thank you for your valuable note.